# Fine-Grained Hardness for Undirected Hamiltonicity

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms, hamiltonian-paths, fine-grained

The fastest known algorithm for detecting Hamiltonian cycles in directed graphs on $n$ nodes runs in essentially $2^n\text{poly}(n)$ time.
However, for *undirected* graphs on $n$ nodes, there is [an algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.0541) running exponentially faster, which takes $1.657^n\text{poly}(n)$ time.

Do we have any interesting conditional lower bounds ruling out substantially faster exact algorithms for detecting Hamiltonian cycles in undirected graphs?
Is there any constant $\epsilon > 0$ for which getting a $(1+\epsilon)^n$ time algorithm for this problem would refute some plausible conjectures about the exact time complexity of other problems of interest?

Comment: We don't know how to prove a $1.99^n$ lower bound for directed Hamiltonicity nor $1.6^n$ for undirected Hamiltonicity under well-established hardness assumptions. But you can get a lower bound of $(1+\varepsilon)$ from SETH for an explicit $\varepsilon>0$. For this, just take any standard reduction from SAT to HAM. It will construct a graph with $C(n+m)$ vertices for a fixed constant $C>0$, where $n$ and $m$ are the numbers of SAT variables and clauses. By the sparsification lemma, you can essentially ignore the $m$ term, which would lead to a lower bound of $2^{n/(C+\delta)}$ under SETH.